# Is it possible to make multiple splines to be sampled in a 'sample curve' node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

Summarizing: I have a spline on the ground that is instancing other vertical splines ('poles'), then I'm copying the ground spline and sampling each point to a different pole driven by a factor. This factor decides where the created spline's points will be along the poles.

My question is: Is there how to create several ground curves and put each of them in a different factor.

In case it doesn't or it's too complicated, will that be possible when the 'repeat zone' launches in Blender 4.0?

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Sorry.... sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! It something like that. Still have to fine tune it. I did something similar with a blind a while ago, had to remember the path and adapt a bit. It's not quite there yet, but it's good to see it working! Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it!

[image]

There: better yet! Thats exactly what I wanted, only missing a map range or something like that to put the 'bottom' and 'top value' always between 0-1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

X problem: yes, that's what *Curve* index is for:

[image]

Y problem: you can loft the pole-curves to 'fill' it with another geometry, if that another geometry has already correct topology. Here calculating that topology is trivial, it's a simple grid. You can delete vertical lines of that grid, which won't affect horizontal edges and vertex indices. You could just spawn a horizontal curve and use duplicate elements node to accomplish the same with less nodes, but I wanted to show how you can wrap anything around those poles. The pole-curves can also be modified prior…

[image]

[image]

### Sample Curve workflow

Back to the X problem if you really need to do it this way, I tried to rationalize it by using bezier curves with auto handles:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But, the reason why I want the 'sample curve' is to slide the horizontal bars in a different rate each, based on their index number, so e.g. if there is 10 bars the last one dislocates 1/10th in relation to the 1st one (or the top most one) through the pole's lenght.

Comment: @AAAYerus either move the points of poles, based on some algorithm, e.g. use a map range, from min 0, from max 1, pass z coordinate as value, and modify to min and to max based on fields… Or when you sample the curve in the option #2, code in some logic (I don't know, e.g. pass the factor of current curve to math: sine), and use that as the sampled factor instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking. =p I need a way of almost precisely position it with a syncronized distribution, almost like a curtain but vertically.

Comment: Will we be able to do this by 'repeat zone'?

Comment: @AAAYerus here's an example on how you'd apply a sine to the heights of the wires: https://i.imgur.com/tKrlEvX.png https://i.imgur.com/HdWomn4.png